# When user clicks on AppBarButton on CommandBar, data in the last textbox that had focus is not updated (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a simple page of data where the user fills in 2 fields (first name and last name) and clicks on a Save `AppBarButton` on a `CommandBar`.

Both these fields use `x:Bind` with `Mode=TwoWay` to load/update the values.

If the user fills in the textbox for first name, then fills in the textbox for last name and hits the Save AppBarButton on the CommandBar, while the focus is still on the Last Name textbox, only the first name is updated.

However, I also created a regular `Button` on the page and if the user does the same thing and uses this button instead, both fields update as expected.

**How can I get the AppBarButton on the CommandBar to work the same way as the regular button and update all the data without adding a lot of code behind?**

Here is the simple class definition that I have:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="mySampleApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="MyPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CommandBar Grid.Row="0"  DefaultLabelPosition="Right" >
            <!-- Save button on a command bar-->
            <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save" LabelPosition="Default" Click="saveStuff_Click" />
        </CommandBar>

        <!-- Sample Data to save-->
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Row="1" Header="Enter Your First Name" Text="{x:Bind currentUserData.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="First Name"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" Grid.Row="2" Header="Enter Your Last Name" Text="{x:Bind currentUserData.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Last Name"/>

        <!-- Save button using a regular button that calls the same function-->
        <Button x:Name="saveStuff" Grid.Row="3" Content="Save" Click="saveStuff_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace mySampleApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        //variables to use in XAML x:Bind
        private UserData currentUserData = new UserData();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void saveStuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sampledata.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentUserData, Formatting.Indented));
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Data saved to: " + file.Path.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Data Saved: FirstName: " + currentUserData.FirstName + "; LastName: " + currentUserData.LastName);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by leaving all textbox bindings as is (using `x:Bind`) and only updating the `AppBarButton` on the `CommandBar` with `AllowFocusOnInteraction="True"`.

Now it looks like this and everything works as expected:

```
<AppBarButton AllowFocusOnInteraction="True" Icon="Save" Label="Save" LabelPosition="Default" Click="saveStuff_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in the official documentation (scroll down to `UpdateSourceTrigger)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#xbind-and-binding-feature-comparison), `x:Bind` on `TextBox.Text` waits for the text box to lose focus to forward its content to the Viewodel. In contrast to a normal `Button` which steals context from the text box, it seems that when using the `AppBarButton` the focus stays on the text box (as you mentioned yourself), so the binding property is never updated.

Setting the binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` would probably resolve the issue sind it forces the bindig to be refreshed on every key press, but unfortunately this is not supported by `x:Bind`. So I guess yout best option is to use a traditional `Binding`:

```
Text="{Binding currentUserData.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Does that mean in order to use the buttons on the CommandBar, I need to move from `x:Bind` to `Binding`? :(

Comment: Well, only on `TextBox.Text` bindings (all other bindings will be updated instantly anyway). Alternatively, you might build some view-code logic to move the focus to some dummy control whenever an `AppBarButton` is tapped, but (unless you have a very specific reason to stick with `x:Bind`, other than the usual "it's compile-time type-safe and faster") this sound like overkill to me.

Comment: @andreask, your answer is fine however the accepted answer by slayernoah is what I was looking for (and I believe it is also what others are looking for)